# Using a Timer to draw graphics scrolling across JFrame

Tags: java, graphics, timer

I'm Making a program that displays a building, some clouds, and trees with Java Graphics. I would like to use a Timer to scroll the clouds across the screen. I'm not sure how to use the timer to continually loop the clouds after it reaches the end of the JFrame

timer is on 126-147

cloud method is on 184 - 239

I have tried to put all the Timer code within the Cloud drawing method but I can't figure out how to use the variable that is tied to the timer to make the clouds move inside the method for the clouds.
Currently, I just have most of the timer stuff outside of the method, and then using 3 different cloud methods, which is redundant.

I'm very new to java so sorry if I have basic mistakes.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Elevator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private final int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 800;
    private final int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 600;

    private JPanel guiPanel, buttonPanel;
    private DisplayPanel display;
    private JLabel Title;
    private JButton Floor;
    private JComboBox Select;


    int locX, locY;
    final int LIMIT = 10;
    final int NUM_ROWS = 10;
    final int WINDOWWIDTH = 12;
    final int WINDOWHEIGHT = 25;
    final int WINDOWSPACING = 10;
    final int FLOORSPACING = 30;
    final int FLOOROFFSET = -10;
    final int ELEVATOR_COLUMN = 5;

    private static final  int NUM_ITERATIONS = 10;  //number of floors for combo box selection
    private int lvlChoice; //variable holding elevator level choice for item event

    private int buildX, buildY, buildW, buildH;  //building height dem

    Color drkGrn = new Color ( 49, 216, 91);   //building ground color
    Color flWind = new Color (163, 156, 77);  //default floor window color
    Color bldCol = new Color (176, 201, 212);  // building color
    Color crntFl = new Color (255, 247, 0);   //current floor color for elevator
    Color blu1 = new Color ( 157, 215, 255 );  //cloud colors
    Color blu2 = new Color (93, 172, 227);
    Color blu3 = new Color ( 62, 167, 240);
    Color blu4 = new Color (136, 156, 169);
    Color blu5 = new Color (209, 230, 245);
    Color plmLeaf = new Color (  6, 145, 84);
    Color trunk =new Color (   170, 85, 0);

    //graphics variables
    final  int tWidth = 10;
    final int tHeiht =120;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Elevator frame = new Elevator();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.initializeVariables();

        frame.setUpGUI();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initializeVariables() {
        locX = 300;
        locY = 150;
        buildX = locX-20;
        buildY = locY-10;
        buildH =375;
        buildW =250;
        lvlChoice = 1;

    }

    public void setUpGUI() {
        Container window = getContentPane();  //you attach Jcomponents to this pannel
        display = new DisplayPanel();
        guiPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        //TODO add title panel
       /* Title = new JLabel("Elevator");
        Title.setFont(new Font(" San Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        titlePanel.add(Title);*/

        Floor =new JButton("Floor");
        Floor.addActionListener(this);

        Select = new JComboBox();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            Select.addItem(String.valueOf(i + 1)); //this takes the int value and the parses it to a string
        }


        buttonPanel.add(Select);
        buttonPanel.add(Floor);


        window.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(guiPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        window.add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    //cloude1 timer, moviment
    Timer tm1 = new Timer(60, this);
    int x1 = 800, velX1 = 3; //position of x on cloud and velociity of cloudes

    //cloude1 timer, moviment
    Timer tm2 = new Timer(50, this);
    int x2 = 700, velX2 = 2; //position of x on cloud and velociity of cloudes

    //cloude1 timer, moviment
    Timer tm3 = new Timer(75, this);
    int x3 = 777, velX3 = 2; //position of x on cloud and velociity of cloudes

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lvlChoice = Integer.parseInt((String) Select.getSelectedItem());
        display.repaint();

        //make only one of these simplfiy the "x1" to x
        x1 = x1 - velX1;  //every 2 milliseconds and 2 to the position of x whitch starts at 0
        x2 = x2 - velX2;  //every 2 milliseconds and 2 to the position of x whitch starts at 0
        x3 = x3 - velX3;  //every 2 milliseconds and 2 to the position of x whitch starts at 0
    }

    class DisplayPanel extends JPanel {
        DisplayPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT));
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }


        //executes all paint methods
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            backDrop(g2d);
            cloud1(g2d, 100, 45);
            cloud3(g2d, 50, 30);
            buildingLoop(g2d);
            cloud2(g2d, 240, 40);
            tree(g2d, 140, 400);
            tree(g2d, 500, 400);
            tree(g2d, 650, 470);
            tree(g2d, 600, 420);
            tree(g2d, 190, 390);
            tree(g2d, 45, 425);
            tree(g2d, 75, 450);
        }

        //static background objects (ground, trees, ect..)
        public void backDrop(Graphics2D g2d) {

            g2d.setColor(drkGrn);
            g2d.fillRect(0,500,getWidth(), getHeight());

        }
        //new method custom for cloudes
        public void cloud1(Graphics2D g2d, int y, int CLDSIZE) {

            //cloud 1
            //y starts at 100 to be put in method argument
            g2d.setColor(blu4);
            g2d.fillOval(x1, y, CLDSIZE, CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu1);
            g2d.fillOval(x1 + 15, y-10, CLDSIZE, CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu3);
            g2d.fillOval(x1 + 30, y+10, CLDSIZE, CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu2);
            g2d.fillOval(x1 + 45, y-10, CLDSIZE, CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu5);
            g2d.fillOval(x1 + 57, y, CLDSIZE, CLDSIZE);
            tm1.start(); //start the timer


        }





        public void cloud2(Graphics2D g2d, int y, int CLDSIZE) {
            //cloud 2
            g2d.setColor(blu5);
            g2d.fillOval(x2, y, CLDSIZE,CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu4);
            g2d.fillOval(x2+15, y-20, CLDSIZE,CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu2);
            g2d.fillOval(x2+30, y+10, CLDSIZE,CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu3);
            g2d.fillOval(x2+45, y-20, CLDSIZE,CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu1);
            g2d.fillOval(x2+57, y, CLDSIZE,CLDSIZE);
            tm2.start(); //start the timer

        }

        public void cloud3(Graphics2D g2d, int y, int CLDSIZE) {
            //cloud 3
            //y starts at 30
            g2d.setColor(blu3);
            g2d.fillOval(x3, y, CLDSIZE,CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu2);
            g2d.fillOval(x3+15, y-10, CLDSIZE,CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu4);
            g2d.fillOval(x3+30, y+10, CLDSIZE,CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu5);
            g2d.fillOval(x3+45, y-10, CLDSIZE,CLDSIZE);
            g2d.setColor(blu1);
            g2d.fillOval(x3+57, y, CLDSIZE,CLDSIZE);
            tm3.start(); //start the timer

        }

        public void tree(Graphics2D g2d, int xPoint, int yPoint){
            int leafSize =25;

            g2d.setColor(trunk);
            g2d.fillRect(xPoint+25,yPoint,tWidth, tHeiht);

            g2d.setColor(plmLeaf);
            g2d.fillOval(xPoint,yPoint, leafSize, leafSize);
            g2d.fillOval(xPoint+5,yPoint-10, leafSize, leafSize);
            g2d.fillOval(xPoint+5,yPoint+10, leafSize, leafSize);
            g2d.fillOval(xPoint+10,yPoint, leafSize, leafSize);
            g2d.fillOval(xPoint+10,yPoint+10, leafSize, leafSize);
            g2d.fillOval(xPoint+30,yPoint-10, leafSize, leafSize);
            g2d.fillOval(xPoint+30,yPoint+10, leafSize, leafSize);
            g2d.fillOval(xPoint+35,yPoint, leafSize, leafSize);
            g2d.fillOval(xPoint+35,yPoint+10, leafSize, leafSize);

        }


        //building the building and windows for the building
        public void buildingLoop(Graphics2D g2d) {

            g2d.setColor(bldCol);
            g2d.fillRect(buildX, buildY, buildW, buildH);
            g2d.setColor(flWind);
            for (int j = 1; j <=NUM_ROWS; j++) { //draws row
                for (int i = 0; i <= LIMIT; i++) { //draws window's
                    if (i == ELEVATOR_COLUMN && j == NUM_ROWS - lvlChoice + 1) {
                        g2d.setColor(crntFl);
                    }
                    g2d.fillRect (i* (WINDOWWIDTH + WINDOWSPACING) + buildX + WINDOWSPACING, buildY + j * FLOORSPACING - FLOOROFFSET, WINDOWWIDTH , WINDOWHEIGHT);
                    g2d.setColor(flWind);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried to put all the Timer code within the Cloud drawing method but I can't figure out how to use the variable that is tied to the timer and get that value passed from the actual parameter that is entered from the method.

Currently, I just have most of the timer stuff outside of the method, and then using 3 different cloud methods, which is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I'd write it:
If you have any questions you're welcome to ask :)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Elevator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private final int   DISPLAY_WIDTH   = 800;
    private final int   DISPLAY_HEIGHT  = 600;

    private JPanel          guiPanel, buttonPanel;
    private DisplayPanel    display;
    private JLabel          Title;
    private JButton         Floor;
    private JComboBox       Select;

    int         locX, locY;
    final int   LIMIT           = 10;
    final int   NUM_ROWS        = 10;
    final int   WINDOWWIDTH     = 12;
    final int   WINDOWHEIGHT    = 25;
    final int   WINDOWSPACING   = 10;
    final int   FLOORSPACING    = 30;
    final int   FLOOROFFSET     = -10;
    final int   ELEVATOR_COLUMN = 5;

    private static final int    NUM_ITERATIONS  = 10;   // number of floors for combo box selection
    private int                 lvlChoice;              // variable holding elevator level choice for item event

    private int buildX, buildY, buildW, buildH; // building height dem

    Color   drkGrn  = new Color(49, 216, 91);   // building ground color
    Color   flWind  = new Color(163, 156, 77);  // default floor window color
    Color   bldCol  = new Color(176, 201, 212); // building color
    Color   crntFl  = new Color(255, 247, 0);   // current floor color for elevator

    // an array with all your clouds
    private Cloud[] clouds;
    private Tree[]  trees;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Elevator frame = new Elevator();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // added the cloud initialization in there
        frame.initializeVariables();

        frame.setUpGUI();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // starts ticking each 30 ms
        frame.tick();
    }

    private void tick()
    {
        // while loop for ever and ever
        while (true)
        {
            // ticks all the clouds
            for (int i = 0; i < clouds.length; i++)
            {
                clouds[i].tick();
            }
            // updates the JFrame graphics
            display.repaint();
            // pauses the ticking for 30 ms
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public void initializeVariables()
    {
        locX = 300;
        locY = 150;
        buildX = locX - 20;
        buildY = locY - 10;
        buildH = 375;
        buildW = 250;
        lvlChoice = 1;
        // puts 3 clouds in our array
        clouds = new Cloud[] { new Cloud(800, 100, 45, 3, true), new Cloud(700, 50, 30, 2, false),
                new Cloud(777, 240, 40, 2, false), };
        trees = new Tree[] { new Tree(140, 400), new Tree(500, 400), new Tree(650, 470), new Tree(600, 420),
                new Tree(190, 390), new Tree(45, 425), new Tree(75, 450) };
    }

    public void setUpGUI()
    {
        Container window = getContentPane(); // you attach Jcomponents to this pannel
        display = new DisplayPanel();
        guiPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        // TODO add title panel
        /* Title = new JLabel("Elevator");
         Title.setFont(new Font(" San Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
         titlePanel.add(Title);*/

        Floor = new JButton("Floor");
        Floor.addActionListener(this);

        Select = new JComboBox<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++)
        {
            Select.addItem(String.valueOf(i + 1)); // this takes the int value and the parses it to a string
        }

        buttonPanel.add(Select);
        buttonPanel.add(Floor);

        window.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(guiPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        window.add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        lvlChoice = Integer.parseInt((String) Select.getSelectedItem());
        display.repaint();

        // moves each cloud by the respective velocity
        for (int i = 0; i < clouds.length; i++)
            clouds[i].x -= clouds[i].velX;
    }

    class DisplayPanel extends JPanel
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        DisplayPanel()
        {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT));
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        // executes all paint methods
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            backDrop(g2d);

            for (Cloud c : clouds)
            {
                if (!c.Foreground) c.draw(g2d);
            }
            buildingLoop(g2d);
            for (Cloud c : clouds)
            {
                if (c.Foreground) c.draw(g2d);
            }
            for (Tree t : trees)
            {
                t.draw(g2d);
            }
        }

        // static background objects (ground, trees, ect..)
        public void backDrop(Graphics2D g2d)
        {

            g2d.setColor(drkGrn);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 500, getWidth(), getHeight());

        }

        // building the building and windows for the building
        public void buildingLoop(Graphics2D g2d)
        {

            g2d.setColor(bldCol);
            g2d.fillRect(buildX, buildY, buildW, buildH);
            g2d.setColor(flWind);
            for (int j = 1; j <= NUM_ROWS; j++)
            { // draws row
                for (int i = 0; i <= LIMIT; i++)
                { // draws window's
                    if (i == ELEVATOR_COLUMN && j == NUM_ROWS - lvlChoice + 1)
                    {
                        g2d.setColor(crntFl);
                    }
                    g2d.fillRect(i * (WINDOWWIDTH + WINDOWSPACING) + buildX + WINDOWSPACING,
                            buildY + j * FLOORSPACING - FLOOROFFSET, WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT);
                    g2d.setColor(flWind);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

class Cloud
{
    int x = 800, y, velX = 3; // position of x on cloud and velociity of cloudes

    final Color blu1    = new Color(157, 215, 255); // cloud colors
    final Color blu2    = new Color(93, 172, 227);
    final Color blu3    = new Color(62, 167, 240);
    final Color blu4    = new Color(136, 156, 169);
    final Color blu5    = new Color(209, 230, 245);

    int     Size;
    boolean Foreground;

    public Cloud(int x, int y, int Size, int velX, boolean Foreground)
    {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.Size = Size;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.Foreground = Foreground;

    }

    public void tick()
    {
        x -= velX;
        if (x < -100) x = 1000;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
    {
        // cloud 1
        // y starts at 100 to be put in method argument
        g2d.setColor(blu4);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, Size, Size);
        g2d.setColor(blu1);
        g2d.fillOval(x + 15, y - 10, Size, Size);
        g2d.setColor(blu3);
        g2d.fillOval(x + 30, y + 10, Size, Size);
        g2d.setColor(blu2);
        g2d.fillOval(x + 45, y - 10, Size, Size);
        g2d.setColor(blu5);
        g2d.fillOval(x + 57, y, Size, Size);
    }
}

class Tree
{
    int xPoint, yPoint;

    public Tree(int xPoint, int yPoint)
    {
        this.xPoint = xPoint;
        this.yPoint = yPoint;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
    {
        int leafSize = 25;

        // graphics variables
        final int tWidth = 10;
        final int tHeiht = 120;
        final Color plmLeaf = new Color(6, 145, 84);
        final Color trunk = new Color(170, 85, 0);

        g2d.setColor(trunk);
        g2d.fillRect(xPoint + 25, yPoint, tWidth, tHeiht);

        g2d.setColor(plmLeaf);
        g2d.fillOval(xPoint, yPoint, leafSize, leafSize);
        g2d.fillOval(xPoint + 5, yPoint - 10, leafSize, leafSize);
        g2d.fillOval(xPoint + 5, yPoint + 10, leafSize, leafSize);
        g2d.fillOval(xPoint + 10, yPoint, leafSize, leafSize);
        g2d.fillOval(xPoint + 10, yPoint + 10, leafSize, leafSize);
        g2d.fillOval(xPoint + 30, yPoint - 10, leafSize, leafSize);
        g2d.fillOval(xPoint + 30, yPoint + 10, leafSize, leafSize);
        g2d.fillOval(xPoint + 35, yPoint, leafSize, leafSize);
        g2d.fillOval(xPoint + 35, yPoint + 10, leafSize, leafSize);

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, That works Just how I wanted it. I don't completely understand how you used the separate classes for the clouds and the trees though.

Comment: Thanks that was extreamly helpfull!

Comment: I'd recommend you really read through this since classes are an essential tool to have and they are what make java a lot more powerful: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link. I really want to know how to implement this in the future for other programs. :) thanks again